# Only allow integration into a branch in perforce

Tags: permissions, perforce

Is it possible to only allow a merge into a branch and no direct check-ins in perforce?

A very simplistic view of what I am trying to do is, if we have two branches, Dev and Release, I would like to allow developers to check in changes directly into Dev, but only merge to Release from Dev, hence avoiding making changes directly on the release branch.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Perforce server trigger awhile ago to solve this particular problem. You can find it at: https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/files/guest/matt_attaway/bash-scripts/noedits.sh

In your case the trigger entry would be:

```
no_edits change-submit //Depot/Rel_Stream/... "bash noedits.sh %clienthost% %client% %changelist% %serverport%"
```

Comment: Sounds like the way to go.  Unfortunately we are on a windows environment but I will translate your script and post back.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.

You simply need to edit the permissions table to restrict access to the Release stream.

I will always recommend that you manage permissions by group rather than individual...its just a nightmare to maintain otherwise.  So lets assume you have a group named **developer** and you want them to write to the Dev stream and able to read the Release Stream.

Your table entry would look something like this.

```
write group Developer * //Depot/Dev_Stream/...
read group Developer * //Depot/Rel_Stream/...
```

Now, with only read access to the release stream they will not be able to merge or copy code up to the release stream/branch.  They will be able to merge/copy code down to the development stream though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  We don't have a release manager, so the developers are trusted and would need to merge code into release themselves.  The question I have is would it be possible to allow them to check in MERGE changes into release but not file changes that are made directly on that branch.  I am not entirely sure if what I am asking is possible as they may not be differentiated, but it would avoid accidental changes on the release branch.

Comment: Well you could do one of two things (at least that come to mind, there may be other options) write a 'form-in' trigger to restrict submitting changes (other than merges) to the release stream, this would require a script of some sort (I am not adept at scripting) or you could simply grant individuals write access to the release stream at the time the merge needs to be done...that is what I would suggest unless merges happen constantly.